# Source for Bloody Fruits Story

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, agada-stories-legends

Recall reading a story when I was younger, pretty sure in a kid's book of Midrash/Aggadah, like Our Sages Showed The Way.

Trying to find the original source, could be have some details wrong.

Someone who was killed and buried by a fruit tree, and the next year the tree produced especially large juicy fruits. A passing gentile officer noticed the fruits and was offered one, but found them to be bloody. The truth came out that the owner killed him.

Comment: That story appears in a book called Jewish Fairy Tales and Legends (or something like that), in that book, it is set in a Middle Eastern country where the Jew was killed by a non-Jew who was jealous of his position of favour in the royal court. The non-Jew killed the Jew and buried him under a fig tree. Next year the fig tree started producing luscious fruits and was the talk of the town. The king came to see the sight and asked the non-Jew the cause of the miracle, who then admitted to his crime. It is perfectly normal for a fig tree to produce good fruits if a body is buried under it.